# Exception handling when open a text file that doesn't exis

Tags: python

Firstly, here is my code ::

```
def tryfirst():
    try:
        f = open('testfile.txt')
    except FirstNotFound as e:
        trysecond()
    else:
        print(f.read())
        f.close()

def trysecond():
    try:
        f = open('test_file.txt')
    except StillNotFound as e:
        print(e)
    else:
        print(f.read())
        f.close()

tryfirst()
```

What am I trying to accomplish?

I would like my program to try to open a text file that doesn't exist (testfile.txt), and after it tries that one, if it fails it moves onto the next one that does exist (test_file.txt) and prints the contents of the file. I want it to initiate the program by calling the first function, tryfirst, as done at the bottom of the code.

When I try to run this, I get the following and not sure why ::

```
NameError: global name 'FirstNotFound' is not defined
```

Comment: `FirstNotFound` What is this? `IOError`? Did you define those exceptions previously by subclassing the exception class?

Comment: If that is what you would expect to get when the system attempts to open a file that doesn't exist, then yes.

Comment: That's beyond my current level of Python knowledge thus far, unfortunately.

Comment: Uh, what do you expect? You haven't defined those exceptions so that's why you are getting a `NameError`. Also, `open` wouldn't throw them anyway... Have you tried to see what exception is actually thrown when you try to open a file that doesn't exist?

Comment: Just replace `FirstNotFound/StillNotFound` with `IOError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can't name your exceptions anything. [Exception docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html) from python as great source of info. In your case replace `FirstNotFound` and `StillNotFound` with `IOError`

Answer (score 1):

you dont have anything named `FirstNotFound`
what you are looking for is `IOError`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :-

```
def readFile():
    try:
        f = open('testfile1.txt')
        print(f.read())
        f.close()

    except OSEroor as e:
        f = open('testfile2.text')
        print(f.read())
        f.close()
```